# Stuck with default table-alias in root criteria Hibernate 3.6

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I want to change the table-alias of the executed sql to `temp` instead of `this`.
However, setting the new alias with `getSession().createCriteria(Vehicle.class, "temp");` won't change the outcome.

As stated I'm using Hibernate Criteria API.

I'm stuck with Hibernate **3.6.10.Final** at the moment.

what I got:

```sql
/* criteria query */ select this_.vehicle_id as y0_, this_.vin as y1_,this_.initial_registration as y2_ from vehicle this_ where this_.vin=?
```

what I was expecting:

```sql
/* criteria query */ select temp.vehicle_id as y0_, temp.vin as y1_,temp.initial_registration as y2_ from vehicle temp where temp.vin=?
```

simplified example

```java
protected List<T> findByProjectionCriteria() {

    Criteria cr = getSession().createCriteria(Vehicle.class, "temp");
    cr.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Vehicle.class));

    ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("vehicleId"), "vehicleId");
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("vin"), "vin");
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("initialRegistration"), "initialRegistration");
    cr.setProjection(projectionList);

    cr.add(Restrictions.eq("vin", "WVW29343249702776"));
            
    begin();
    
    List<T> list = null;
    try {
        list = cr.list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (list == null)
        list = new ArrayList<T>();

    commit();
    return list;
}
```

entity

```java
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

import javax.persistence.*;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "vehicle")
public class Vehicle {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "vehicle_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int vehicleId;
    
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 17)
    private String vin;
    
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "initial_registration")
    private Date initialRegistration;
    
}
```

What can I do to enforce the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at the source-code and how the root-alias is handled by Hibernate.

The list-method in SessionImpl, which is called from my method, creates a new CriteriaLoader-object, which also calls the constructor of the CriteriaQueryTranslator-object, where also the default root alias is set.

In the **CriteriaQueryTranslator**-constructor the following method is called
which is responsible for setting up the alias in the query.

```java
private void createCriteriaSQLAliasMap() {
    int i = 0;
    Iterator criteriaIterator = criteriaEntityNames.entrySet().iterator();
    while ( criteriaIterator.hasNext() ) {
        Map.Entry me = ( Map.Entry ) criteriaIterator.next();
        Criteria crit = ( Criteria ) me.getKey();
        String alias = crit.getAlias();
        if ( alias == null ) {
            alias = ( String ) me.getValue(); // the entity name
        }
        criteriaSQLAliasMap.put( crit, StringHelper.generateAlias( alias, i++ ) );
    }
    criteriaSQLAliasMap.put( rootCriteria, rootSQLAlias );
}
```

In this method my alias is added to the map in the while-loop, but afterwards gets replaced in the map because of the identical key, which is the class of my Entity in form of a criteria.